# javascript fake instanceof

Tags: javascript, oop, constructor

I'm trying to create a "constructor" of sorts using this pattern:

```
function mything() {
    var a, b, c;
    ...
    return {
        publicFunc: function() {
            //access private vars here
        }
    };
}

//usage

mything1 = mything();
mything2 = mything();
```

The thing is, I also want to have it pass an `instanceof` test:

```
assert(mything1 instanceof mything === true);
```

Is there any way to do this? Using regular constructors won't work because the prototype functions can't access private vars.

Comment: In order for `instanceof` to return true, the constructor's `prototype` must be in the instance's prototype chain.

Answer (score 4):

You would need to use a slightly different design pattern to have private variables and have it be an instanceof `mything`:

```
function mything() {
    var a, b, c;
    ...
    this.publicFunc = function() {
            //access private vars here
        }
    };
}

//usage

var mything1 = new mything();
mything1.publicFunc();
var mything2 = new mything();
```

Answer (score 1):

It is technically possible, but you can solve your problem more elegantly (explanation follows below):

```
function mything() {
  var a, b, c;

  function PrivateConstructor() {
    this.publicFunc = function() {}
  }

  // this is the magic that makes it happen:
  PrivateConstructor.prototype = mything.prototype; 

  return new PrivateConstructor();

}

mything1 = mything();
assert(mything1 instanceof mything); // passes
```

Or, with EcmaScript 5 features:

```
function mything() {
  var a, b, c;

  var object = Object.create(mything.prototype);
  object.publicFunc = function() {}

  return object;
}

mything1 = mything();
assert(mything1 instanceof mything); // passes
```

## Explanation

The `instanceof` operator will yield true if the right-hand operand is a function, and the object stored in the `prototype` property of that function is contained by the prototype chain of the left-hand side operand.

The first example reuses `mything.prototype` as “prototype” property for another, temporary function that is only used to produce one object (with `mything.prototype` in its prototype chain). The second example creates such an object by inheriting from `mything.prototype` directly with [`Object.create()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create).

Both objects inherit from `mything.prototype` and will therefore pass the `object instanceof mything` test.

That being said, the pattern proposed by jfriend00 has less overhead and is easier to read while provideing the functionality you wanted to have.